# How to check if an object exist or not in angular js?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

Is there any way to know that an object exist or not in HTML. I have an object like this.

```
$scope.object = {name : 'usman', profession : 'developer'}
```

Now i want to know in Html if the object exist or not or does the object contain only a text like this .

```
$scope.object = "Usman";
```

Now there are my conditions.

```
    <div ng-if="object">
    <p>Object exist and have attributes</p>
    </div>

    <div ng-if="object">
    <p>object contain only string no attributes exist</p>
   </div>
```

I want to write a combine condition like this - that if the object has no attributes and contains only string then show the div.

Here it is .

```
 <div ng-show="!objecthasnoattributes and objectOnlyContainsString">
<p>show this </p>
    </div>
```

Now how can I do this ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It can be more short with a single method:

**HTML:**

```
<div ng-if="isObject()">
  <p>Object exist and have attributes</p>
</div>

<div ng-if="!isObject()">
  <p>object contain only string no attributes exist</p>
</div>
```

**Controller:**

```
$scope.isObject = function() {
  return typeof($scope.object) === 'object';
}
```

**UPDATED:**

If you want only string to be displayed,

```
$scope.isString = function() {
  return typeof($scope.object) === 'string';
}
```

**Then you need only one html:**

```
<div ng-if="isString()">
  <p>Show this</p>
</div>
```

[**Here is a changed plunk**](https://plnkr.co/edit/xspMhdsLMGB4YVIyBP3D?p=preview)

Comment: actually in html I want the condition in one place no seperrate

Comment: you want only string to be displayed?

Comment: see the plunker https://plnkr.co/edit/XgEPKUL2Fm0I1dclytIV?p=preview and this condition    ng-show="$parent.customPopupSelected && $parent.customPopupSelected" play with it

Answer (score 1):

You can write as below.

```
<div ng-if="object !== undefined"> </div>
```

And to check type of var is OBJECT or STRING... you can do as follow.

```
    $scope.object = {
        name: 'usman',
        profession: 'developer'
    };

    $scope.myString = "Usman";

    $scope.isString = function(val) {
        return typeof val === 'string';
    }
    $scope.isObject = function(val) {
        return typeof val === 'object';
    }
```

Then check as below for types.

```
    <div ng-if="object !== undefined && isObject(object)">
        <p>Object Value </p>
    </div>
    <div ng-if="myString !== undefined && isString(myString)">
        <p>String value</p>
    </div>
```

Ask for more queries

Thanks

Comment: See updated Answer. Ask me for more query. Happy to help. :)

Answer (score 1):

You can make much easy way.

```
$scope.object = {name : 'usman', profession : 'developer'};

$scope.getBType = function(test){
  return( typeof test);
}

<div ng-if="getBType(object)=='object' && getBType(object.name)=='string'">
<p> Show this</p>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are certain that the input `object` will be of following types only.

```
$scope.object = {name : 'usman', profession : 'developer'};

$scope.object = "Usman";
```

The you can simply use:

```
<div ng-if="object && object.name">
    <p>Object exist and have attributes</p>
</div>

<div ng-if="object && !object.name">
    <p>object contain only string no attributes exist</p>
</div>
```

Only if the object exists and has name property, the condition #1 will be met.